# CAEmitterCell color property not working

Tags: ios, swift, colors, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I have some strange behaviour of CAEmitterCell color property or I don't understand it right.

I have a cell

```
let cell = CAEmitterCell()
```

With content of simple .png file which is drawn black

```
cell.contents = UIImage(named: "particle")?.cgImage
```

And I try to change it to green

```
cell.color = UIColor.green.cgColor
```

But it is still rendered black.
I tried to change "Render as" property of this image to "Template imagr" in media asset but it has no effect.

Can anyone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have image under particle ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Do you have image with name particle in the bundle of the project?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk yes, sure. Actually the question is about changing the color of this image.

Comment: I provide working example try it in you're environment

Answer (score 13):

Ok, the case was the color of initial image: the darker the image - the less color variation you have. So better use white images for your particle emitters %)

Comment: I always forget this!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example how you can change color of the `CAEmitterCell`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        createParticles()
    }

    func createParticles() {
        let particleEmitter = CAEmitterLayer()

        particleEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: -96)
        particleEmitter.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine
        particleEmitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 1)

        let red = makeEmitterCell(color: UIColor.red)
        let green = makeEmitterCell(color: UIColor.green)
        let blue = makeEmitterCell(color: UIColor.blue)

        particleEmitter.emitterCells = [red, green, blue]

        view.layer.addSublayer(particleEmitter)
    }

    func makeEmitterCell(color: UIColor) -> CAEmitterCell {
        let cell = CAEmitterCell()
        cell.birthRate = 3
        cell.lifetime = 7.0
        cell.lifetimeRange = 0
        cell.color = color.cgColor
        cell.velocity = 200
        cell.velocityRange = 50
        cell.emissionLongitude = CGFloat.pi
        cell.emissionRange = CGFloat.pi / 4
        cell.spin = 2
        cell.spinRange = 3
        cell.scaleRange = 0.5
        cell.scaleSpeed = -0.05

        cell.contents = UIImage(named: "images")?.cgImage
        return cell
    }

}
```

And example of the animation.

[image]

Comment: I use the exact same code taken from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-emit-particles-using-caemitterlayer